# Calculate the percentage of students who submitted homework late

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a Table of homework submission hours from multiple schools.

The table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|Student | School | homework submission hours (timestamp)|
--------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get the percentage of students that took them more than an hour to submit homework for each school?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, I tried to get all the homework submission hours, and summarize them by the school.                                                                                                           customMetrics
| summarize count() by school

Comment: Can you post that code please? You'll need some form of code to do what you're asking.

Comment: (i'm also interested to know what class you're taking where about querying app insights/logs, that's exciting all by itself!)

Comment: wait, maybe i misinterpreted: is this question FOR homework?  or about a table of homework?  or somehow both?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is homework (possibly) i don't want to give a full concrete example, but will explain some ways to get where you want to go?

`countif` operator can be used to count if rows meet a condition.

is hours in your table a *duration*?  or a literal timestamp?  the question says "more than an hour", but does it mean "more than an hour **ago**" ?  and the grid says "submission hours" but then says it is a timestamp?  it probably isn't both.

so you could have

- `summarize countif(timestamp < ago(1h))`, that would count the number of items that occurred more than an hour ago (the timestamp is before an hour ago)
- or possibly `summarize countif(hours > 1h)` if the hours value is a timespan, not a timestamp?

you can use that example to add a `by` to the summarize by school.

to calculate a percent, you need the full count and the matching count, so you'd probably have something like

```
| summarize total=count(), subset=countif(somecriteria) by something
| project something, percent = subset / (total * 1.0) * 100
```

things to think about:

- can the same student go to more than one school?
- can the same student submit hours more than once?

if so, you might also need to look at `dcount` instead of `count`, or different summarizations like `avg` as well?

that will really depend on what's in the rows